# How to place 3d objects on top of augmented images with a specific order

Tags: java, android, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore

What I am trying to do is a little treasure hunt app with augmented images. Since I am a beginner, there might be something that I am getting wrong in my code. The thing is that I need to validate if the user is looking for the augmented images in the correct order (Meaning that he or she should not be allowed to skip an image, if that happens a message should be displayed and no 3d model should be rendered). The user will receive a hint (Toast) saying where he/she should look for the next augmented image. That hint will only be shown if the user is following the correct order of images. If the user is in the correct order, a 3d model will be displayed on top of the augmented image. When the user touches the 3d model, a message will appear (hint that indicates the next image).

So, my problem is that the loop checking for a match between any augmented image in my augmented-database and a frame in the real world , is checking all conditions at the same time (at least it looks like it is). In my example, I am using only two images to understand the issue better (I will be adding more later). Let's suppose that the correct order is image1-image2 (image 1 first , then image 2). When I look for the second image first (in the incorrect order), there is no 3d model shown and a message saying that the user is facing the wrong image is shown. The problem comes afterwards, when I go back to the correct image again( image 1). What happens is that both models (from image1 and image2) are rendered together on top of image1, whereas only the model related to my image1 should have appeared (since I am in the correct order now). I wish to make each model only appear on top of the correct augmented image and only when the image is seen in the correct order.

Here the part of my code that checks for images in the real world:

```
private void onUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime) {
        Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
        Collection<AugmentedImage> augmentedImages = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);

        //This loop is constantly comparing every frame seen in the real world (by our phone camera) with the
        // images contained in our augmented images Database. When an image caught by our camera matches any image in our
        // database and that image is seen in the correct order , a 3d object is going to be placed on top
        // of that image (This is supposed to only happen ONCE per image - using the method placeOBject).

        for (AugmentedImage augmentedImage : augmentedImages) {
            if (augmentedImage.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {


                //Each one of the if statements below check a certain image included in our database. And every nested if/else
                // statements check if the images were captured in the correct order (Meaning that no image has been skipped).
                if (augmentedImage.getName().equals("muriloCard") && imgCont1==0) {
                    placeObject1(arFragment, augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()), Uri.parse("models/MagnifyingGlass.sfb"));
                    imgCont1++;
                }
                if (augmentedImage.getName().equals("earthAugmented") && (imgCont2==0)) {
                    if (textSeen1 == true && (imgCont1!=0)){
                        placeObject2(arFragment, augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()), Uri.parse("models/Present.sfb"));
                        imgCont2++;
                    }else if (textSeen1 == false) {
                        Toast.makeText(arFragment.getContext(), "You are in image EARTH. You are in the wrong image.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textSeen1 = true;
                    }

                }
```

As you can see, my first image (image1) is "muriloCard" and the second (image 2) is "earthAugmented". The problem I already stated occurs when I look at "earthAugmented" first and then at "muriloCard" afterwards. Every if statement should be checked separately but is seems that the for loop above checks them at the same time , meaning that as soon as the

```
imgCont1
```

is incremented, it looks like both if statements are satisfied and both objects (a present and a magnifying glass) are placed at the same time using both methods below:

```
placeObject1(arFragment, augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()), Uri.parse("models/MagnifyingGlass.sfb"));
placeObject2(arFragment, augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()), Uri.parse("models/Present.sfb"));
```

So instead of placeObject1 being called when the first image is seen and placeObject2 being called when the second image is seen, both are called at the same time when my first image is seen(only after the second one was already seen). Is there a way to modify that behavior?